# Android user input of a hex byte value

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Although it's not rocket science I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I'm working with Android connected via USB Accessory to a Hardware device. The HW has values that can be set by the Android User Interface. Many of these values are 8 bit Bytes. So certain Byte fields can be edited by the user and I want to easily get their input and validate it. So basically hex input 0x00 - 0xff 
Just wondering does this already exist out there somewhere? Internet ain't giving me much so it looks like starting from scratch.

Comment: It would be nice of you to accept this answer in case you find it useful, or otherwise comment on it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular `NumberPicker` with a custom `NumberPicker.Formatter` to format the values as hex digits:

```
public class MyFormatter extends NumberPicker.Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(int value) {
        if(value < 0x10) {
            return "0" + Integer.toHexString(value);
        }
        return Integer.toHexString(value);
    }
```

}

And then use:

```
...

myNumberPicker.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
// use this to disable keyboard input
myNumberPicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

...
```

Screenshot of NumberPicker with hex `Formatter`:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for that info but the Android Number inputs seem to be limited to Decimal input. I ended up using the keyboard for the moment.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear; my method does not allow you to enter the values using the keyboard (actually it does, but it's confusing, since the keypad is decimal only).

Comment: Whilst the NumberPicker will work it just don't seem elegant for selecting a byte value. So the range is 0 to 255. The Number Picker works great for limited range but for that type of range it strikes me as a cumbersome input mechanism.

Comment: Some people might thing such scrolling user interface is nice; actually it's terrible when a hexadecimal keyboard would do: It' much more efficient!

Comment: I found this (not tried): https://github.com/troido/hex-input